# Comparing acidic strength of phthalic acid isomers

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds, carboxylic-acids

I'd like to compare the acidic strengths of phthalic, isophthalic and terephthalic acids. As I understand, phthalic acid is the most acidic due to steric inhibition of resonance (SIR), but as terephthalic acid has a negative mesomeric effect (−M) operating, it should be more acidic compared to isophthalic acid.

However, the data from Wikipedia suggests that isophthalic acid is more acidic:

| Acid | Structure | $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1}$ | $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Phthalic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phthalic_acid) | [image: Phthalic acid] | $2.89$ | $5.51$ |
| [Isophthalic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isophthalic_acid) | [image: Isophthalic acid] | $\color{red}{3.46}$ | $4.46$ |
| [Terephthalic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terephthalic_acid) | [image] | $\color{red}{3.51}$ | $4.82$ |

Also, why is there such tiny difference in their acidic strengths?

Comment: even I believe that the acidity order should be phthalic acid > terephthalic acid > isophthalic acid for all the reasons you already mentioned.  I'm not sure about the reason for the discrepancy but I believe that the pKa values here are likely to be more accurate cause it is specified that they are measured at a constant temp 25 C. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/3527600418.mb8899isme0025

Comment: pka1 phthalic acid - 2.76      pKa1 terephthalic acid - 3.52    pKa isophthalic acid - 3.70

Comment: do anyone know some factors which effects acidic behavior but are not very frequently used in deciding acidic strength orders?

Comment: Pthalic acid tops the list of acidic strength among the three because of the famous ORTHO effect in organic chemistry according to which, irrespective of the nature of substituent on ortho position, ortho derivatives are the strongest acid.